# Populate Ajax data every 5secs replacing the old data jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, data-structures

I am trying to create a set of rules where the data from API returns in the html page with 6 different API. So what I need is, every 5secs new data to be displayed replacing the old data.

This is what I have done so far:

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tohfz61x/3/

Here what I did is, added `setInterval function` but it didn't work.

In this version, it's getting all the data at once and displaying the last of the loop. but i need to display 1 at a time till 6 time.

So basically if the first result is $50, after few seconds, it should change to another value ($30 for example) as in the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `initLoadData()` inside a `setTimeout()` with a condition as below.

```js
var value = 1;

initLoadData();

function initLoadData() {

  var ajaxTime = new Date().getTime();
  var dataURL = "https://adler.blockrize.io/data/" + value;

  $.getJSON(dataURL, function(response, status, t) {
    var rewardsEarnedHolder = $('#rewardsEarned');
    var totalReward = '<span class="price">$' + response.RewardsEarned.TotalReward + '</span>';
    rewardsEarnedHolder.html(totalReward);
    console.log(dataURL);

    value++;
    if (value <= 6) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        initLoadData(value);
      }, 2000);
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="transaction-section bg-dark text-white pb-4">
  <h2>Transaction History</h2>
  <div id="rewardsEarned"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call **`setTimeout()`** function after API call is finished

```js
var i = 1;
initLoadData();

function initLoadData() {
  var dataURL = "https://adler.blockrize.io/data/" + i;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data.RewardsEarned.TotalReward;
      i = i + 1;
      if (i <= 6) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          initLoadData();
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", dataURL, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div class="transaction-section bg-dark text-white pb-4">
  <h2>Transaction History</h2>
  <div id="rewardsEarned">$<span id="price">00.00</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of delay function,just make these changes in your code

Replace this:

```
rewardsEarnedHolder.html(totalReward);
```

With this code

```
rewardsEarnedHolder.html(totalReward).delay(5000);
```